# Understanding wedge products for differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am trying to understand the derivation of coordinate expression for the Laplace-Beltrami operator (wiki [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator)). The Wikipedia page says that $\nabla\cdot X$ is an operator mapping a function to a function. This would mean that $\text{vol}_n=\sqrt{\vert g\vert}dx^{1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n$ is a function on the manifold. How is this function defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Vol}{vol}$In the page you link, $\Vol_{n}$ isn't a function, but a non-vanishing differential form of top degree, $n$.

The Lie derivative $L_{X}(\Vol_{n})$ of the volume form with respect to the vector field $X$ is also a form of top degree, hence a scalar function multiple of $\Vol{n}$. (At each point of an $n$-manifold, the space of $n$-forms is one-dimensional.) This scalar function is *defined* to be the divergence $\nabla \cdot X$ of $X$, i.e.,
$$
(\nabla \cdot X) \Vol_{n} = L_{X}(\Vol_{n}).
$$

Comment: I am not seeing how the expression $\left(\nabla\cdot X\right)\text{vol}_n$ makes sense if $\left(\nabla\cdot X\right)$ is an operator on a function space but $\text{vol}_n$ is not a function. How would the divergence of $X$ even act on that wedge product?

Comment: Just as in multivariable calculus, $\nabla \cdot X$ is a function; it "acts" on $\Vol_{n}$ by ordinary, pointwise multiplication. Note, however, that the divergence $\nabla \cdot X$ of a vector field $X$ is not itself the Laplace-Beltrami operator $\nabla^{2}$, it's just "scaffolding": The formula $\nabla^{2} f = \nabla \cdot (\nabla f)$ defines $\nabla^{2}$ on an arbitrary $C^{2}$ function $f$.

Comment: I will take a closer look into it. Thanks.