# Divergence of vector field on manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-derivative

This is a follow-up question to the one I made [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1755422/understanding-wedge-products-for-differential-forms). On the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator), the divergence of a vector field $X$, denoted $\nabla\cdot X$, is defined as the function satisfying $\left(\nabla\cdot X\right)\text{vol}_n=L_X\text{vol}_n$. The page gives $\nabla\cdot X=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\vert g\vert}}\partial_i\left(\sqrt{\vert g\vert}X^i\right)$, where $X^i$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ component of the vector field $X$.

If I evaluate $\text{vol}_n$ at $\left(\partial_1,\dots,\partial_n\right)$ then $\text{vol}_n\left(\partial_1,\dots,\partial_n\right)=\sqrt{\vert g\vert}$. This leaves $\left(\nabla\cdot X\right)\text{vol}_n=\partial_i\left(\sqrt{\vert g\vert}X^i\right)$.

On the other hand, if I use the fact that the $L_X\left(f\right)=X\left(f\right)$ for smooth functions, then $L_X\left(\text{vol}_n\left(\partial_1,\dots,\partial_n\right)\right)=L_X\left(\sqrt{\vert g\vert}\right)=X\left(\sqrt{\vert g\vert}\right)=X^i\partial_i\left(\sqrt{\vert g\vert}\right)$.

Clearly something has gone wrong. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all of your statements are correct. Especially is the LHS of $(\nabla \cdot X) \mathrm{vol}_n = L_X \mathrm{vol}_n$ evaluated at $(\partial_1, \dots, \partial_n)$ equal to $\partial_i(\sqrt{|g|} X_i)$. (But take care, although this is probably what you meant, you wrote another (wrong) equality.)

The RHS of $(\nabla \cdot X) \mathrm{vol}_n = L_X \mathrm{vol}_n$ evaluated at $(\partial_1, \dots, \partial_n)$ equals 
$$(L_X \mathrm{vol}_n) (\partial_1, \dots, \partial_n)) $$$$= X(\mathrm{vol}_n (\partial_1, \dots, \partial_n)) - \mathrm{vol}_n(L_X \partial_1, \partial_2, \dots, \partial_n) - \dots -  \mathrm{vol}_n(\partial_1, \dots, L_X \partial_n)$$

Substituting your second statement and $L_X \partial_k = [X^i \partial_i, \partial_k] = X^i[\partial_i, \partial_k] - \partial_k(X^i) \partial_i = - \partial_k(X^i) \partial_i $ in gives:
$$(L_X \mathrm{vol}_n) (\partial_1, \dots, \partial_n)) = X^i \partial_i (\sqrt{|g|}) + \partial_i (X^i) (\sqrt{|g|}) = \partial_i (X^i \sqrt{|g|}) $$

where the last equality comes from the product rule.

Comment: Hello. I am interested in knowing how to get the first line involving $\left(L_X\text{vol}_n\right)\left(\partial_1,\dots,\partial_n\right)=\dots$. Is bringing the Lie derivative inside the argument one of its properties?

Comment: Also, is $X^i\left[\partial_i,\partial_k\right]=0$ because $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\left(f\circ x^{-1}\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\left(f\circ x^{-1}\right)$ by the commutative property of partial derivatives for smooth functions?

Comment: For your second comment: Yes, that's why coordinate vector fields commute. For your first question: Depending on how you initially defined the Lie derivative it is either one of it's defining properties or one of the properties easily derived from it's definition. Maybe you want to read the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative, especially the section about the Lie derivative of tensor fields.